# Electron - How to detect maximize event?

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to change maximize icon when the window is maximized.

How can i detect when the window maximized by double click on the title bar or by moving the window top of the screen.

Without running isMaximized() constantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the `maximize` or the `enter-full-screen` event on your current window. The difference is that `maximize` is called when window is maximized but the `enter-full-screen` is called when the user maximized the window. You can read more about these events [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window)

```js
mainWindow.on('maximize', () => {
    // do something
})
```

or

```js
mainWindow.on('enter-full-screen', () => {
    // do something
})
```